# Detection of pills using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I would like to know if there is a clever way to segment individual pills using edge detector (e.g Canny) in the following image (without somekind of CNN or other ML way):

[image]

So far I have tried to use the Canny dector on a filtered image (box/gauss, with k=(3,3) or k=(5,5)) on different channels of several color spaces, e.g. GRAY, HSV, LAB. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a perfect edges for several different experiments. If I could find the edges segmentation would already be quite simple, because I could compare the different colors of the pills and their sizes.

I thought that it could be done in another way: apply masks to the image corresponding to each pill and then find the edges on the filtered image, however, this method seems primitive and it will be difficult to distinguish between two-colored pills.

Best I can get so far:
[image]

Comment: Separating touching pills is impossible without an algorithm that is aware of the shape of a pill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you suggest, how could I approach this problem in a "classical-algorithmic" way? Maybe Invariant template matching (https://github.com/cozheyuanzhangde/Invariant-TemplateMatching)?

Comment: If you have pictures of all the unique pills beforehand, then yes, it should be possible to find them with template matching / homography. It would be slow though.